# How to make sure the value copied depends on the value of variable on the other sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy one column in sheet 2 to another sheet.
But the value depends on the following conditions:

1. If Sheet1 = 0 then copy **H103** in Sheet2 to Sheet3 Column D.
2. If  Sheet1 = 1 then copy **H3** in Sheet2 to Sheet3 Column D until 100.
3. If Sheet1=100 then copy **H102**in sheet 2 to sheet3 Column D.

Do I need to write condition until Row 104 or what can I do. Help me please!

```
SrcNodeld = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").Column
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
     
If SrcNodeld = 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Numbers("H103").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    Columns("D").Select
    ActivateSheet.Paste
ElseIf SrcNodeld = 1 Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Numbers("H3").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    Columns("D").Select
    ActivateSheet.Paste
ElseIf SrcNodeld = 2 Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Numbers("H4").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    Columns("D").Select
End If
```

Yes I want to use for loop but just don't know how.

**Sample Data:**
[image: sample]

Comment: You could possibly use a loop in here. But I'm not sure what you want to achieve. I tried to edit your question to make sense of it but there are still something amiss. What do you want to compare between Sheet1 and Sheet2? Also what is Tx?

Comment: I want to copy a value in sheet 2 to sheet 3. But the value varies and depend on what it wrote on the cell on sheet 1:column C. If sheet1:columnn= 0 then copy *H103,sheet2*. @L42

Comment: I mean what value specifically in Column C? Sheet1 = 0? What equates to 0 in Sheet1? If you can provide a screen shot of how your data is organized that would be helpful.

Comment: I can't add picture since I need to have a least 10reputation.
Example value of column c is :
                                              cell1=0
                                             cell2=8
                                             Cell 3=0
                                             cell 4= 20

the quantity in the cell between (1 to 100) but the cells in column C is until C2000

Comment: http://imgur.com/GYS5Ana
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope i understand it right:

Macro start in sheet1.C1 until sheet1.Cx is empty. If sheet1.Cx = 0 then copy sheet2.Dx (start D103) to sheet34.Hx (start H1)

```
Sub copy()
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim sheet34 As Worksheet
Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set sheet34 = Worksheets("Sheet34")
i = 1
j = 103 'start sheet34 H103
While Not IsEmpty(sheet1.Cells(i, 3)) 'start C1 to empty cell
If sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = 0 Then
sheet34.Cells(i, 4) = sheet2.Cells(j, 8)
End If
i = i + 1
j = j + 1
Wend
End Sub
```